# How to debug Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have two main problems with mod_rewrite:

1. There is no meaningful error reported when I have an invalid rule

   [image]
2. To reliably test each modification, I have to erase Google Chrome's cache. This isn't rocket science, but I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, click <kbd>OK</kbd>, and close the window, and reload.

I'd like to see if any of the gurus are willing to share their secrets to efficiently managing mod_rewrite code.

Comment: Puk, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules where I discuss some of the stanbdard tricks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug htaccess rewrite script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738170/how-to-debug-htaccess-rewrite-script)

Answer (score 314, accepted):

One trick is to turn on the rewrite log. To turn it on, try this line in your Apache HTTP Server main configuration or current virtual host file (**not** in `.htaccess`):

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
```

Before Apache [httpd 2.4 mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging), such a per-module logging configuration did not exist yet. Instead you could use the following logging settings:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Comment: thanks. It's not what I was looking for, but still better than nothing.

Comment: You cannot put this in .htaccess. You have to put it in the VirtualHost configuration.

Comment: You cannot do this in `.htaccess`. `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` are available only in server config and virtual host context

Comment: You have to have the `RewriteEngine On` section there too because if you only enable it (as i did) in the `.htaccess` file, then nothing will be logged.

Comment: where is the log file located in apache 2.4?

Comment: You'll find the 2.4 log items in the relevant error log. This may depend on your configuration, but default Debian/Ubuntu setups have them in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Pro tip: Remember to turn your rewrite logging off. If you forget you'll fill your hard disk up fairly promptly, especially on a production server.

Comment: @chacham15, I do that all the time, put `RewriteLog` in a config file but don't set `RewriteEngine on` until the `.htaccess` file. Always works for me.

Comment: This is not working in Apache 2.4. Before start wasting time, check Tobias Schultze answer below.

Answer (score 156):

The RewriteLog directive as [mentioned by Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite/9632952#9632952) is not available any more in Apache 2.4.

You need to use the LogLevel directive instead. E.g.,

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
```

See *[Apache Module mod_rewrite, Logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging)*.

Comment: where is the log file associated with this?

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII - The logfile is the error log (specified by ErrorLog directive).  Per docs, you can get just the rewrite messages with grep: `tail -f error_log|fgrep '[rewrite:' `

Comment: don't forget to restart apache

Comment: I had to make sure `AllowOverride` was set to `All`!

Comment: And where do we put this snippet? Inside the virtualhost? Inside .conf?

Comment: Followed instructions, doesn't work. apache2 restarts successfully but no rewrite log entries are put into any file in /var/log/apache2

Answer (score 31):

For basic URL resolution, use a command line fetcher like `wget` or `curl` to do the testing, rather than a manual browser. Then you don't have to clear any cache; just <kbd>up arrow</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a shell to rerun your test fetches.

Comment: Another trick is to use Chrome "Porn mode" (Ctl+Shift+N).  When you close the window, any cached session context is trashed.

Comment: I think Firefox's "private session" browsing also. But are you saying this this context is per individual window (so you're not closing Chrome?)

Comment: AFAIK, Chrome and Ff are different in that Ff runs as a single process which is in private mode or not.  With Chrome, each tab or window runs as a separate process and can be individually in private mode; close a private window/tab and it context is trashed.

Comment: PrivateTab addon for FF does the thing. Each tab works individually.

Comment: This method also shows redirects!  Nice for someone that doesn't have access to the machine apache config file.

Answer (score 25):

There's the [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

It shows which conditions were tested for a certain URL, which ones met the criteria and which rules got executed.

It seems to have some glitches, though.

Comment: For me it showed a green executed rule in the last line without any code.

Comment: @thombr can you be more precise, please? The link does not work? Or the tool? What exactly doesn't work? And why is that relevant in context of this question?

Comment: This tells me that the URL is being transformed as expected... however on the actual server I am getting a 404

Comment: @michael is the tested rule the only one present in your configuration? Is mod_rewrite actually installed and active?

Comment: Turns out overrides were not enabled

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632952/194894), you could do the following when running Apache  on Linux (Debian in my case).

First create the file *rewrite-log.load*.

**/etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite-log.load**

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Then enter

> $ a2enmod rewrite-log

followed by

> $ service apache2 restart

And when you are finished with debugging your rewrite rules,

> $ a2dismod rewrite-log && service apache2 restart

Comment: This did not work. I get sandino@envy:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                 [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite-log.load:
Invalid command 'RewriteLog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: @sandino, what apache version are you running? It seems this syntax was changed for 2.4, use instead: `LogLevel warn rewrite:trace8` or `LogLevel info rewrite:trace8` where 8 can be any number from 1-8

Comment: AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite
Invalid command 'RewriteLog'

Comment: This is no longer available. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html