# mod_rewrite convert: XXX-YYY to XXX.php?sub1=YYY

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm using an ubuntu LAMP and i'm trying to use mod_rewrite to convert url such as:

- site/XXX to site/XXX.php and
- site/XXX-YYY to site/XXX.php?sub1=YYY

I've used this rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./$1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./$1.php?sub1=$2
```

In local on my OSX they works fine, anyway when uploaded the .htaccess on the ubuntu server, calling site/test i can't reach site/test.php but i get a 404.
Mod_rewrite is working, in fact the 404 page is setted in the same .htaccess and works.
In local i used this in a folder: localhost/myfolder/.... while in remote i'm using the root of a subdomain:
app.sitename.com/....

Can someone help me?

This is the complete code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^altro&(.+)? ./altro.php?$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./$1.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./$1.php?sub1=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./$1.php?sub1=$2&sub2=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./$1.php?sub1=$2&sub2=$3&sub3=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).([a-zA-Z]+)$ ./server/php/files/$1/$2/$3/$4.$5
```

The first directive is working! In fact site/altro&code opens altro.php?code

Comment: Is your rules inside an `<IfModule>` container?

Comment: No. It isn't! Should it is in that container??

Comment: No it doesn't need to be. Are you sure you have `AllowOverride All` or `AllowOverride FileInfo` in your vhost's config?

Comment: Yes i have. In fact other directives such as:
RewriteRule ^altro&(.+)? ./altro.php?$1 [L,QSA,NC]
works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?sub1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

**Full .htaccess code:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^altro&(.+) altro.php?$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php?sub1=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php?sub1=$2&sub2=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php?sub1=$2&sub2=$3&sub3=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).([a-zA-Z]+)$ server/php/files/$1/$2/$3/$4.$5 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Using: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-?$ $1.php [L,QSA]
it works but i'd like to call directly: site/pagename and not site/pagename/ or site/pagename-

Comment: No, it doesn't works. Neither pagename/ or pagename
Only if i use the "-" it works with pagename-
Really don't understand.

Comment: Can you post your latest & complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Yes! Here it is:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^altro&(.+)? ./altro.php?$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./$1.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./$1.php?sub1=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./$1.php?sub1=$2&sub2=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./$1.php?sub1=$2&sub2=$3&sub3=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).([a-zA-Z]+)$ ./server/php/files/$1/$2/$3/$4.$5`
The first directive is working! In fact site/altro&code opens altro.php?code

Comment: Oh its impossible to read it from comments. Edit your question and post this code there.

Comment: Nope. http://app.XXXX.it/test-1 works well but http://app.XXXX.it/test doesn't works:

Not Found
The requested URL /test was not found on this server.

Comment: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: It is pretty late so I am going offline. I will check your comments t=in the morning.

Comment: Q1. It's the only one
Q2. Yes it is. I've pasted your exactly code.
Q3. It is located in /var/www/app that is the folder refered by apache for app.site.it/
THanks

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROOT is `/var/www` OR `/var/www/app` ?

Comment: the document root is /var/www/app in the virtualhost app.site.it

Comment: OMG i found that if i request an unexistent page such as:
site.it/blabla it says: The requested URL /blabla.php was not found on this server.
But ONLY if i use a real filename it doesn't rewrite the url!!!

Comment: Perfect, glad it worked out. Consider accepting the answer now

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps to debug:

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

source: [How to debug Apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite)

(You cannot put this in .htaccess. You have to put it in the VirtualHost configuration.)

Comment: I've tried and i got this at the end:
87.14.78.188 - - [22/Oct/2013:21:53:07 +0200] [app.XXX.it/sid#7ffec18566b0][rid#7ffec16a10a0/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/app/] pass through /var/www/app/test.php

That's seems correct!! The file test.php exists and it is in that folder! Anyway i'm getting:

Not Found

The requested URL /test was not found on this server.