# Apache RewriteCond and RewriteRule to skip for the existing files and directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, redirect

I have the following directory structure for my local site.

```
mysite
|_ css
|_ images
    |_ logo.png
|_ js
|_ app
    |_ index.php
|_ .htaccess
```

I'm trying Apache URL rewriting to redirect to `http://mysite.dev/app/index.php` for non-existing directories. 
For example, `http://mysite.dev/en/home` will be rewritten into `http://mysite.dev/app/index.php`

I have tried this rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ app/index.php [L]   
</IfModule>
```

But it is rewritten for all existing directories and no-existing directories.
That is, when I browse `http://mysite.dev/mysite/images/logo.png`, it is rewritten to `http://mysite.dev/mysite/app/index.php`

I added the line above the two `RewriteCond` lines, but it did not work.

```
RewriteRule ^(images|css|js) - [NC,L]
```

My goal is to skip the rule if any file or directory exists.
How can I write `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` for this purpose?

**[Edit]**
I found the problem. It is because of the virtual host I added for my site. I have the following lines of code in `httpd-vhost.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost mysite.dev>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite"
    ServerName mysite.dev
    ServerAlias mysite.dev
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I browsed `http://mysite.dev/images/logo.png`, the `RewriteCond` is not working properly
But when I removed the virtual host and I browsed `http://localhost/mysite/images/logo.png`, it is working fine and I see the image correctly.

I'm not sure what is the problem and conflict of virtual host and `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Where is your htaccess file?

Comment: Are you sure that `images/logo.png` is visible to Apache?  If not, Apache will treat it as non-existent.  If you remove your RewriteRule, can your host serve `mydomain.com/images/logo.png`?

Comment: turn on rewrite logging http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite

Comment: @Sithu: Are `css` and `images` real directories OR some symbolic links.

Comment: `css`, `images` and `js` are real directories and `images/logo.png` is also visible to Apache. I have to check the apache config or Windows host config because it is perfectly working in the other PC without even `RewriteRule ^(images|css|js)`.

Answer (score 0):

In your virtual host directive you need to have an [`AllowOverride` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#AllowOverride):

```
<VirtualHost mysite.dev>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite"
    ServerName mysite.dev
    ServerAlias mysite.dev
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite">
        AllowOverride FileInfo

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```