# htaccess redirection wont work on local server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i installed apache server on my windows computer but i cant make this htaccess work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ index\.php\?s=([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ %1?%2%3 [L,R=301]
```

This htaccess works perfectly on my paid server (linux) and its supposed to convert queries into paths. Could any misconfiguration be preventing it from working?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check you Apache config file? Most likely the problem is your settings.

If you are using `Apache 2.3.9` or greater the `AllowOverride` setting is `None` by default. Check you httpd.conf or apache2.conf file and look in the `<directory>` section and make sure it says `AllowOverride All` instead of `AllowOverride None`.

Comment: Thanks, it was set to none. I changed to ALL but still doesnt work. What else could it be?

Comment: @CainNuke Make sure you restart Apache services whenever you change the config.

Comment: I did so several times but it still wont work. Its really weird.

Comment: I don't know your config, but make sure it's the correct vhost or <directory>. Change all the AllowOverrides you find in the file to `All`

Comment: I did so. Are you sure it cant be anything else?

Comment: Test your htaccess. Try a simple redirect rule. Also enable rewrite debugging. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite

Comment: Also what path is your htaccess in? and what is your document root?

Comment: Im trying to access locally either via localhost or my local IP