# Apache mod_rewrite looks for foo.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to follow a [mod_rewrite tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708) but I can't get a particular example to work.  I've enabled mod_rewrite and it is working for simple examples like the following `.htaccess`.

```
# Redirect everything in this directory to "good.html" 
RewriteEngine on RewriteRule .* good.html
```

The following code is the contents of my `.htaccess`

```
# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite user URLs
#   Input:  user/NAME/
#   Output: user.php?id=NAME
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ user.php?id=$1
```

I've had a look around and found out [how to log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632952/926667) what mod_rewrite was doing and my logs showed the following information

```
192.168.1.70 - - [03/Jan/1970:20:41:55 +0100] [192.168.1.64/sid#41353678 [rid#417c1518/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/] add path info postfix: /var/www/user.php -> /var/www/user.php/bob
192.168.1.70 - - [03/Jan/1970:20:41:55 +0100] [192.168.1.64/sid#41353678][rid#417c1518/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/user.php/bob -> user.php/bob
192.168.1.70 - - [03/Jan/1970:20:41:55 +0100] [192.168.1.64/sid#41353678][rid#417c1518/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^user/(\\w+)/?$' to uri 'user.php/bob'
192.168.1.70 - - [03/Jan/1970:20:41:55 +0100] [192.168.1.64/sid#41353678][rid#417c1518/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/user.php
192.168.1.70 - - [03/Jan/1970:20:41:55 +0100] [192.168.1.64/sid#41353678][rid#417ae4d0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] add path info postfix: /var/www/user.php -> /var/www/user.php/bob
192.168.1.70 - - [03/Jan/1970:20:41:55 +0100] [192.168.1.64/sid#41353678][rid#417ae4d0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/user.php/bob -> user.php/bob
192.168.1.70 - - [03/Jan/1970:20:41:55 +0100] [192.168.1.64/sid#41353678][rid#417ae4d0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^user/(\\w+)/?$' to uri 'user.php/bob'
192.168.1.70 - - [03/Jan/1970:20:41:55 +0100] [192.168.1.64/sid#41353678][rid#417ae4d0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/user.php
192.168.1.70 - - [03/Jan/1970:20:41:55 +0100] [192.168.1.64/sid#41353678][rid#417bb500/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/bob -> bob
192.168.1.70 - - [03/Jan/1970:20:41:55 +0100] [192.168.1.64/sid#41353678][rid#417bb500/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^user/(\\w+)/?$' to uri 'bob'
192.168.1.70 - - [03/Jan/1970:20:41:55 +0100] [192.168.1.64/sid#41353678][rid#417bb500/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/bob
```

So I understand from the log that the regex is not matching because it is being compared to `user.php/bob` rather than `user/bob`.  If I change the rewrite rule to `^user.php/(\w+)/?$` then it works.  What I don't understand is why Apache is looking for `user.php` when the href doesn't contain `.php`, see below.

```
<a href="user/bob">user/bob</a>
```

Can anyone explain how to make Apache look for `user/bob`?

Also, if possible, can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Is that _everything_ in your htaccess?

Comment: Yes, I just lifted it straight from the tutorial.

Comment: If you change the rule to `RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [R]`, what does it show in the url?

Comment: It just shows `192.168.1.64/user/bob`. If I understand correctly the flag will be applied after a match is made.  The problem I have is prior to checking for a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like multiviews is matching "user" to "user.php" *before* mod_rewrite even gets applied. Try turning it off:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Multiviews is part of mod_negotiation, and it tries to "guess" a requested file by looking for similarly named files (like files minus the extension). It gets applied before mod_rewrite so it will bypass your rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks. I added that code to `.htaccess` and it now works as I expected it to.