# override apache rewrite rules with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

working on a server that hosts multiple domains.
Somewhere in apache config is a rewrite rule that is set for ALL domains.

What happens is if a user goes to example.com/foo they are supposed to get redirected to example.com/foo_bar

However, in one domain, I want to override this behavior so that the url stays at example.com/foo and does not redirect. I've been searching and trying various rules and conditions to no avail. I don't have access to the apache config, but I am using .htaccess for some rewrite rules on this domain.

here's my rewrite rules in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # this isn't working
    # RewriteRule ^(foo)($|/) - [L]

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1

    # this didn't work either
    # RewriteRule ^/foo index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try redirecting `/foo_bar` back to `/foo`.

When Apache processes the rewrite rules it runs through them multiple times, which you can see when you [turn on debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite). I think what's happening in your case is that you're trying to match the URI in the first pass, but Apache has already modified it to `/foo_bar`.

Also, as a matter of debugging, you should try to recreate the problem in an environment you control. Ask your sysadmin for a copy of the global configuration and mirror the set up you're constrained to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create exception for one domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo(/.*)?$ /foo_bar$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```