# WordPress - how to overwrite Apache rewrite rules?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multisite

In my apache host setting, I have this by default,

```
    RewriteCond     %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-f
    RewriteCond     %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-d
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}                          !^/server-status
    RewriteRule     ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)$           /app/os?site=$1 [R,QSA]

    RewriteCond     %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-f
    RewriteCond     %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-d
    RewriteRule     ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/?$      /app/os?site=$1&page=$2 [R,QSA]
```

How can I overwrite that with `.htaccess` for my WP site?

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Currently if I have this on my browser address bar:

```
http://wpxxx.com/app/about
```

it will be rewritten to:

```
http://wpxxx.com/app/os?site=about
```

if I use this:

```
http://wpxxx.com/app/about/
```

I will get this error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /about/ was not found on this server.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found these link's

https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/2r4lfa/whats_the_root_cause_of_htaccess_overwrites/

[override apache rewrite rules with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918327/override-apache-rewrite-rules-with-htaccess)

I hope you will get a solution.

Comment: seen them and tried those too but still not working.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't have any Idea but If I found something I will post it here.

Comment: that is ok. it is something to do with the server that I should configure. thanks