# .htaccess wont work in Ubuntu 14.04 Even with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

Iv'e tried everything, I enabled rewrite module, messed around with the apache config and still my server will not add the .php extension automatically. It just keeps showing a 404 error.

BTW, I have this setup on a virtual host.

Here's my Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port th$
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/ce

        ServerName computingessentials.tk
        ServerAlias www.computingessentials.tk

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
         <Directory /var/www/ce/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
         </Directory>
        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ videos.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ article.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ video.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
```

For example, there is a page called `series.php`, which should get replaced to `/series` but when I go to `/series`, it says file not found.

And you will not be able to access the server since at the moment I have setup my host files to redirect me to the IP.
Tagged In: Getting Started, Apache, DigitalOcean Articles, DNS, PHP, System Tools, Ubuntu

Comment: What is your apache version?

Comment: Just for fun ... pls add following under *RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]* RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L] and try again

Comment: @donald123 doesn't work :(

Comment: Don't bust your head trying to debug rewrites on your own. There are mechanisms for Apache which allow you to log and debug stuff like this. First check your error log and if you don't find anything useful there take a look at the accepted answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite). What config options you choose depends on the Apache version you are using. Makes life easier and guaranteed to hurt less.

Comment: @holodoc tried it, but it does not help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in Ubuntu 14.04 (and Apache 2.4) the default DocumentRoot was changed from `/var/www` to `/var/www/html`

Your Config file says `<Directory /var/www/ce/>`

Try changing it to default

Comment: I have multiple websites and thus cant do that

Answer (score 0):

Try your code this way and check for the existence of your file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ videos.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ article.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ video.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
```