# Friendly URL within a directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, friendly-url

I have a Wordpress installation in a domain and within a directory, I have a site developed in PHP+MySQL completely independent of the wordpress. It works alone. This site is a backoffice, so it's installed under the /backoffice/ directory.

One of the directories of the backoffice I have another directory I want it works with friendly URL's.

In my .htaccess I have the following rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^backoffice/edit_user/([^/\.]+)/?$ /backoffice/edit_user/index.php?o=$1 [L,NC,QSA]


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^postpass/?$ wp-login.php?action=postpass [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ wp-login.php?action=logout [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^lostpassword/?$ wp-login.php?action=lostpassword [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^retrievepassword/?$ wp-login.php?action=retrievepassword [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^resetpass/?$ wp-login.php?action=resetpass [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^rp/?$ wp-login.php?action=rp [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^register/?$ wp-login.php?action=register [QSA,L]
```

When invoked a url like this one: mydomain.com/backoffice/edit_user/joseantonio the 404 page come up.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post all of your .htaccess-es generated by wp.
.htaccess in root
.htaccess in subdir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I could find the solution:

Here is the code used in conjuntion with the wordpress:

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

**RewriteRule ^backoffice/edit_user/([^/\.]+)/?$ /backoffice/edit_user/index.php?o=$1 [L,NC,QSA]**

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^login/?$ wp-login.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^postpass/?$ wp-login.php?action=postpass [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^logout/?$ wp-login.php?action=logout [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^lostpassword/?$ wp-login.php?action=lostpassword [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^retrievepassword/?$ wp-login.php?action=retrievepassword [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^resetpass/?$ wp-login.php?action=resetpass [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^rp/?$ wp-login.php?action=rp [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^register/?$ wp-login.php?action=register [QSA,L]
```

As you can see, I changed the position of my rule after the index.php rule, works fine, in any other position, it will not work.

Answer (score 6):

As it is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632952/2775748) - you can debug your **Apache** rewrites. Turn on `RewriteLog` in your virtual host **OR** server configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Then you'll see what rule makes it to redirect 404.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use own .htaccess in /backoffice/ folder with

```
RewriteBase /backoffice/
# all the backofice rules
```