# Different rewrites for different domains in same htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to find a way make rewrite rules not to interfere with each other.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com
RewriteRule ^old-url.html(.*)$ /new-url-1/? [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com
RewriteRule ^old-url.html(.*)$ /new-url-2/? [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain3\.com
RewriteRule ^old-url.html(.*)$ /new-url-3/? [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain4\.com
RewriteRule ^old-url.html(.*)$ /new-url-4/? [R=301,NC,L]
```

If I access, let's say `www.domain4.com/old-url.html` I'm redirected to `www.domain4.com/new-url-1/`

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: Anyone know how to make this work? Please?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. How should the rewrite know which of the `old-url.hmtl` request should go to which new url? They are all exactly the same in your example.

Comment: Thanks Stephan! That's exactly the problem, isn't there a way to first check the current domain name, for which one the redirect should be executed? In the example I have tested to use a `RewriteCond`on the current domain, but with no luck.

Comment: That makes sense, and yes that should be possible. Have you tried using RewriteLog to debug this and see if the first rule even matches at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite.

Comment: Also, what are you using `(.*)` for in the RewriteRule, and why does the destination URL contain a `?` ?