# Cake PHP 3 | Internal Server Error 500

Tags: .htaccess, internal-server-error, cakephp-3.x, http-status-code-500

On the localhost it is running. But when I upload it, its throwing an 500 error.

I checked:
mod_rewrite (loaded - phpinfo(8))
extension intl (enabled)

I tried:
Deleting all the cache files

Thats my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Errorlog of PHP:

```
[Sun Jan 17 11:04:02 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate wildcard CommonName (CN) `*.webpack.hosteurope.de' does NOT match server name!?
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you look in the server error logs? The exact error message will be there.

Comment: Such problems need to be debugged by yourself, all people can do is guessing, which isn't overly useful. I'd suggest that you start with inspecting your servers error logs, and turn on/up the [**rewrite error level**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite).

Comment: [Sun Jan 17 11:04:02 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate wildcard CommonName (CN) `*.webpack.hosteurope.de' does NOT match server name!?

Thats my error log, I don´t know if it´s the right one tho. I don´t have a server, I am just using Webhosting.

Comment: you are trying to access an https address instead of http, make sure that in your address bar you use http. If you need to use https, you would then need to use your own domain and have the correct certs loaded in the web server

Comment: That´s probably from another Domain. I am not accessing the Cakephp through https

Answer (score 0):

So at the end it was pretty simple and stupid, but maybe it will help someone.

My Webhosting was using PHP 5.3 - Update to 5.6 and e´voila!