# Can i add .htaccess for specific page in child theme using wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to add `.htaccess` for specific page in wordpress child theme. Actually i'm sending category slug in url to `custompostpage.php`  displaying post by category slug. For getting the category slug i'm using `cp=` action at end of the url.

```
http://example.com/demo/project/custom-post-page/?cp=search-engine-marketing
```

Functionality working fine.. But I want to remove the `?cp=` for SEO purpose. For the task i'm using following `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^custom-post-page/([^.]*)$ custom-post-page?cp=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it does not working. I upload this .htaccess file in the child theme (same path of `custompostpage.php`).

Can anyone guide me that can i add .htaccess file in the child theme using wordpress or not? If yes then where i'm doing wrong in my coding.  I would like to appreciate if someone guide me. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule needs fixing as your url doesn't start with `custom-post-page`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)custom-post-page/([^\.]*)$ $1custom-post-page?cp=$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for share the knowledge, but still nothing happening. I added your code but does not working.

Comment: In your original example the `([^.]*)` is wrong as it excludes anything (dot), you forgot to escape that `([^\.]*)`. I fixed my example, should work now. If you have control over the Apache server I recommend [debugging the rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `.htaccess` file does not work. Nothing happening. I place this file on same path where `custompostpage.php` is located...

Comment: If you are using Wordpress you need to edit the already existing `.htaccess` and add the `RewriteRule`