# Htaccess RewriteRule redirects to 404 page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My basic requirement is:

1. Remove **`.php`** extensions from all the urls.
2. Rewrite the urls from *`http://localhost/unsync/softwares/page_name/sub_category/`* to *`http://localhost/unsync/softwares.php?p=page_name&sub_cat=sub_category`*

The following is my **`.htaccess`** code:

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

#Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes

#Error Documents
ErrorDocument 400 /unsync/error.php?code=400
ErrorDocument 401 /unsync/error.php?code=401
ErrorDocument 402 /unsync/error.php?code=402
ErrorDocument 403 /unsync/error.php?code=403
ErrorDocument 404 /unsync/error.php?code=404
ErrorDocument 500 /unsync/error.php?code=500
ErrorDocument 503 /unsync/error.php?code=503

#Remove extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /unsync/$1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule softwares/(.*)/(.*)/$ /softwares.php?p=$1&sub_cat=$2 [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

**The problem I am facing is that, RewriteRule fails. I mean, when I try to access `softwares/page_name/sub_category`, its throwing a 404 error.**

> Note: Its removing the `.php` extensions properly and working fine with normal pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your rewrite rule rewrites all requests to /unsync/request.php, you have to check the existance of php file before rewriting the request,

```
    #Remove extensions
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/unsync/$1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /unsync/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Or you can simply exclude the slash in pattern so that it can not conflict with your other rule

```
    RewriteRule ^([^\/.]+)$ /unsync/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Remove or change The **Options +Multiviews** line to **Options -Multiviews**

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules are tried in order.

This means `softwares/page_name/sub_category` is rewritten by the first rule to `/unsync/softwares/page_name/sub_category.php`, which is not found. Therefore, you get a 404 Not found error.

Comment: Then you must look into rewrite log and debug what's going on, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632952/1741542

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but my error log does not show anything related to this :(

Comment: See the given answer on how to activate the *rewrite* log. Debugging is not an easy task and is more than fits into a simple answer on Stackoverflow.

Comment: XD LOL, k let me do some digging. :)

Answer (score 0):

After a long day of research, I could finally resolve my issue on my own as follow (if anyone facing similar issue is searching for solution):

```
#If both p and sub_cat are issued
RewriteRule ^softwares/(.+)/(.*)$ /unsync/softwares.php?p=$1&sub_cat=$2 [NC,L]

#If only p is issued
RewriteRule ^softwares/(.*)$ /unsync/softwares.php?p=$1 [NC,L]

#Remove extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /unsync/$1.php [NC,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
```