# RewriteRule does not work as expected if requesting itself

Tags: regex, apache2

I want to serve

`http://172.16.0.2/container/app.html/any/path/here`
by `app.html` which is an existing resource.

Plus, I want all my path without any ending extention to be served by  `index.html`. I.e.: `http://172.16.0.2/container/path/randomly/written`

here are my rules:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteRule ^[^.]{1}(?!<\.)[^.]{1,}$   index.html [L]

RewriteRule ^app.html$   - [L]
RewriteRule ^app.html(.*)$   app.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule - [L]
```

- Requesting `app.html` works
- Requesting `index.html` works
- Requesting `index.html/path/pathpath` works (index.html)
- Requesting `index.html/path/pathpath.EXT` works (404)

**BUT**

- Requesting `app.html/a/path` generates a 404 error.

No clue at all, can someone explain me why?

**Logs**

```
172.16.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:10:44:40 +0000] [172.16.0.2/sid#7fc44d87d4c0][rid#7fc44dbd10b8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/applications/container/web/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/applications/container/web/app.html -> /var/www/html/applications/container/web/app.html/sdf/sdf
172.16.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:10:44:40 +0000] [172.16.0.2/sid#7fc44d87d4c0][rid#7fc44dbd10b8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/applications/container/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/applications/container/web/app.html/sdf/sdf -> app.html/sdf/sdf
172.16.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:10:44:40 +0000] [172.16.0.2/sid#7fc44d87d4c0][rid#7fc44dbd10b8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/applications/container/web/] applying pattern '^app.html(.*)$' to uri 'app.html/sdf/sdf'
172.16.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:10:44:40 +0000] [172.16.0.2/sid#7fc44d87d4c0][rid#7fc44dbd10b8/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/applications/container/web/] rewrite 'app.html/sdf/sdf' -> 'app.html'
172.16.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:10:44:40 +0000] [172.16.0.2/sid#7fc44d87d4c0][rid#7fc44dbd10b8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/applications/container/web/] add per-dir prefix: app.html -> /var/www/html/applications/container/web/app.html
172.16.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2016:10:44:40 +0000] [172.16.0.2/sid#7fc44d87d4c0][rid#7fc44dbd10b8/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/applications/container/web/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: /var/www/html/applications/container/web/app.html [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

Comment: Tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite

Comment: @rgoliveira Good point, I updated the question with some useful logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that those rules are set into a `<Directory>` directive, after some previous `RewriteRule` set before the `<Directory>` directive and just straight into the `<VirtualHost>` directive.

According to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), if I set a `RewriteRule` in there, I can only rewrite by specifying **URL**s. I was specifying by thinking about the physical path, though.

> Designates the location on the file-system of the resource to be
>   delivered to the client. Substitutions are only treated as a
>   file-system path when the rule is configured in server (virtualhost)
>   context and the first component of the path in the substitution is
>   exists in the file-system

Two solutions:

- Thinking about URL rewrite
- Move the RewriteRule outside the `<Directory>` directive so that the substitution is well considered as physical path by apache