# Rewrite Rule enable training slash and no slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This question may be duplicated but I search a lot and can't find an answer. So I'm using htaccess file to Rewrite and I want to show the same page using URLs : http://localhost/assoc/about and http://localhost/assoc/about/ .

I call page contents by " include_once " and pages are located in directory /www/assoc/astc/ . When I tape for example http://localhost/assoc/about it works but with the training slash, it redirects to 404 page.

Here is my htaccess. Thanks.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ([a-z]+)$ astc/accueil.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ astc/accueil.php?page=$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ([a-z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ astc/accueil.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ astc/accueil.php?page=$1&id=$2 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/assoc/page-non-trouvee
```

Comment: Is this .htaccess placed in `/www/assoc/astc/ ` directory?

Comment: Your `.htaccess` file is very badly formed, and makes very little sense whatsoever. Leading slashes are not supported in `.htaccess`, and the condition at the top will only apply to the first rule, and nothing after that. Also, the last rule only has one parameter `(.*)`, but is trying to get data for two (`$1` and `$2`). I highly recommend that you read through the documentation and various guides available, otherwise you are going to continue having problems without learning how things really work.

Comment: I will read through the documentaion so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems. This line

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ astc/accueil.php?page=$1 [R=301,L]
```

redirects all the requests into `astc/accueil.php?page=`

I also suggest to [remap instead of redirect your requests](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

This `^/(.*)$` regex catches all the requests so it is impossible for the remaining rewrite rules being evaluated.

[Try adding rewrite log to debug your regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite)

Comment: I will check that and try to resolve the issue. I haven't read enought documentation about rewriting so, I missed a lot of things. I will reback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you already have it, try adding the following line to your htaccess

```
DirectorySlash On
```

Comment: I tend to use a virgin htacces to test a particular item. You have plenty of redir stuff sitting there, which may interfere at some point. If it doesn't break your host, try the slash thing with a clean htaccess first, then add one item a time to make sure you know where it gets buggy. Good luck tweaking.

Comment: I continue to find a way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So finally it's working with this content :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ([a-z]+)(/?)$ astc/accueil.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ([a-z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(/?)$ astc/accueil.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/assoc/page-non-trouvee
```

Thanks to all of you.