# htaccess redirect if hostname is NOT

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, phpmyadmin

I'm running a server with multiple vhosts and phpMyadmin is set up as an alias which can be access via anydomain.com/phpmyadmin. I would like to use an .htaccess redirect rule so that if phpmyadmin is NOT accessed on the *server-admin-url*, the visitor is redirected to, say, Google.

The correct URL would be: `https://server.domain.com:9090/phpmyadmin`

Could anyone help me, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way you can do this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^server.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Maybe you want also check the port, then use

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^9090$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^server.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/$1 [L,R]
```

**Update**

Reading again your question I see you're also trying to switch from http to https.

I suggest to add a check if https is off:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^server.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/$1 [L,R]
```

If your VirtualHost is configured with https you should pay particular attention to how [VirtualHost matching works](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/details.html)

Comment: Hi, freedev. Thanks a lot. The redirect works nicely if phpMyadmin is loaded on a different host. But if I simply use server.domain.com/phpmyadmin, i.e. without the 9090 port, it still loads.

My main problem is that without the port, it won't get the correct SSL certificate. What's the best solution here?

Comment: I think the real question is how do I include the two conditions as "either - or". I tried putting the one with the port first and then adding `[OR]` at the end, but it wouldn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @zkvvoob Had you tried to add second rule? Just like my answer, but in this case add only `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !9090` just before the `RewriteRule`. It should work fine (without using any `[OR]`)

Comment: Yes, I've done this. Like I said, the redirect works fine if the domain is wrong, but if the port is missing - it doesn't work, i.e. phpMyadmin still loads (but with the incorrect SSL certificate).

Comment: This is should work, I have updated `RewriteCond` in my answer just to be more clear, anyway suggest to enable the rewrite debugging http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite

Comment: Hello. Tried your second suggestion (with the port), but when I go to `https://server.maindomain.com:9090/phpmyadmin` I'm redirected to Google!
Here's the apache error log: http://pastebin.com/Z3ScuwMJ
Could you help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: @zkvvoob I don't see the `RewriteCond` part in the piece of log you have posted in pastebin, there is only the `RewriteRule` part. Have you truncated the log? Or double check if there is a second `.htaccess` into `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`. Where have you placed your  `.htaccess`? Could you post your `.htaccess` entirely?

Comment: Thank you for not giving up! There is no other .htaccess file in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` where I've put mine. According to the Apache vhost, this is the directory behind the `/phpmyadmin` alias. Here's the full content of the .htaccess, there's nothing there besides your lines (note that the port IS correct): http://imgur.com/a/73kkt
As for the apache error.log, I followed the instructions here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging and used `tail -f` as described on the same page to get the results I shared with you earlier.

Comment: Regarding the log, may be you had a low verbosity. Anyway, I have updated my answer hope this new suggestion helps.