# URLRewrite - Rewritten url is not working

Tags: java, url-rewriting

Following is my configuration:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/xf/(.*)$</from>
    <to>/xfDetail?id=$1</to>
</rule>
```

The url I visited is `http://mydomain/xf/63e2d96047754072a340610`. But it says that the page cannot be found.

Do I configure it incorrectly?

This is my working one:

```
<rule>
    <from>/jr</from>
    <to>/jr/index</to>
</rule>
```

By the way, are there any ways debugging this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be that I had another rule which handles the request like this:

```
<rule>
    <from>/xf</from>
    <to>/xf/index</to>
</rule>
```

The default matching type for `URLRewrite` is regex, so my request url matches `/xf`, then the actual url is `/newHouse/index/xxxxx`. Obviously there's no this page existed.

So, in order to get it working, I have to change it to this:

```
<rule>
    <from>/xf$</from>
    <to>/xf/index</to>
</rule>
```

The `$` is needed at the end of the `from`.

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule will not match with any URL because it requires '/' right after previous domain.

So, the rule should be:

```
^xf/(.*)$
```

And, Here is explaination

[image: Explain]

If you're using Apache and mod_rewrite, you can have a look at this question: [How to debug Apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Thank you. But seems it's not working for my case ToT

Comment: I've found the root cause as shown in my answer. The  `^/xf/(.*)$` is from the manual, it's my first time using this, not sure if there's any difference comparing to the older version. Thank for your help anyway.