# redirect with multiple query

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-parameters

I've been searching for hours now but cannot find the working solution for this problem. I'm redesigning a website and need to redirect a bunch of old url's to new url's. The basic format is something like:`pages/page.php?m=22&p=33`should go to something like `mainpage/subpage/` while completely ignoring all parameters. After having tried multiple variations I currently have this (as part of a Wordpress site) in my htaccess. The problem arises when having 2 parameters in the url to redirect instead of 1 or none.

```html
# REDIRECTS FROM OLD WEBSITE
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# custom redirects
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=([0-9]+)&p=([0-9]+)$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^pages/all_inclusive_zeildag\.php$ /bedrijfsuitjes/volledig\-verzorgd\-zeilen/ [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
# END REDIRECTS OLD WEBSITE

# BEGIN WordPress
all the usual wp code
#
# END WordPress
```

I have almost got this working. Problem is the second parameter. Properly redirected are:
 [pages/all_inclusive_zeildag.php?m=8](http://57755478.swh.strato-hosting.eu/pages/all_inclusive_zeildag.php?m=8) and if I redirect without any parameter at all.

But the problem is:[/pages/all_inclusive_zeildag.php?m=8&p=22](http://57755478.swh.strato-hosting.eu/pages/all_inclusive_zeildag.php?m=8&p=22) which leads to a 404

Any insight are more than welcome.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

The first two are not being picked up by this rewriterule, as expected.

The 3rd is actually doing exactly what you're asking it to do:

http://57755478.swh.strato-hosting.eu/pages/all_inclusive_zeildag.php?m=8&p=22

Results in a 301 towards:
http://57755478.swh.strato-hosting.eu/bedrijfsuitjes/volledig-verzorgd-zeilen/?m=8&p=22

(Use devtools network tab, and turn on preserve logs if you're using chrome)

If you intended the query string to be stripped, then you'll need to append a question mark to the redirect url:

RewriteRule ^pages/all_inclusive_zeildag.php$ /bedrijfsuitjes/volledig-verzorgd-zeilen/? [R=301,NC,L]

Also for clarity, group the RewriteCond statements together with the rewrite rule, since they will only apply to the first RewriteRule following them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A *"nice"* way to see what is happening while processing the rewrite rules is using the [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and [RewriteLogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) directives in [Apache 2.2 mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Or in [Apache 2.4 mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) using the regular [LogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) directive:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

See also: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632952/832620

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Thanks for all the input. Somehow it got me on the right track and I ended up with

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^pages/all_inclusive_zeildag\.php /bedrijfsuitjes/volledig-verzorgd-zeilen/%1? [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^pages/avondopleiding\.php /leren-zeilen/avondles-zeilen/%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```