# www and https redirects not working as desired

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, virtual-hosts

I can't seem to get myredirects to work as desired. My objectives are:

1. Redirect http://example.com to https://www.example.com
2. Redirect http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com

Objective 1 has aleady been achieved, but the problem is redirection http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com, and its actually resulting to a 404 error. I used [Ryte](https://ryte.com) to identify the issue which is as below:

```
https://enmowe.com/ (403) is not reachable
http://enmowe.com/ (301) is forwarding to https://www.enmowe.com/ (200)
https://www.enmowe.com/ (200) is available
http://www.enmowe.com/ (404) is not reachable
```

I have tried the following in my Apache VirtualHost:

**Method 1.**

```
    <If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.enmowe.com'">
        Redirect "/" "https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1"
    </If>

    <If "%{SERVER_PROTOCOL} != 'HTTPS'">
        Redirect "/" "https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1"
    </If>
```

**Method 2.**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.\.enmowe\.com)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.enmowe.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

**Method 3.**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =enmowe.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Kinda feel lost right now

Comment: Does apache have a virtual host entry for www.enmowe.com because if it doesn't then the rewrite rules cannot fire....

Comment: www.enmowe.com has been set as the ServerAlias in the virtualhost

Answer (score 2):

You want to redirect if the protocol isn't right *or* the hostname. So you should formulate these two conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.enmowe.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.\.enmowe\.com)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.enmowe.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

The fact that `https://enmowe.com` isn't reachable at all is not tied to this. If you want it to be reachable and you have the right certificate add the hostname as an `ServerAlias` to the definition of the https server.

BTW: Please remove `virtual-hosts` tag as it's not related to your question.

Comment: Thanks, this only works partially to. It sets the url to https://www when its http://enmowe... or http://www.enmowe... However, https://enmowe... still doesn't redirect to https://www.enmowe...

Comment: This may be due to the regex i copied from your question. I didn't test. Enable [rewrite debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite) and have a look whether the second condition matches.

Comment: This is what I have in the enmowe.com.com vhost file:

`RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.\.enmowe\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]`

This is based on your answer. However, still `https://enmowe.com` doesn't seem to get redirected.

I also added:

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.\.enmowe\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]`

Really strange. I created a vhost for `www.enmowe.com`.

Comment: However, as I stated before `http://enmowe.com` and `http://www.enmowe.com` are being redirected to `https://www.enmowe.com` as desired.