# Workaround issue of Helicon Ape .htaccess RewriteRule from modifying Content Type

Tags: .htaccess, iis-7.5, coldfusion-10, cfwheels, helicon-ape

**Issue:**

Using .htaccess in IIS7.5 using Helicon Ape with the last RewriteRule which when left uncommented drops the Content-Type from the Response Headers as viewed by Chrome inspector (see example screen captures below). This occurs to the /flex2gateway/ path which should produce a Content-Type of application/x-amf:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/index.cfm/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*/index.cfm/(.*)$ ./rewrite.cfm/$1 [NS,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(flex2gateway|jrunscripts|cfide|cfformgateway|cffileservlet|railo-context|lucee|files|images|javascripts|miscellaneous|stylesheets|robots.txt|favicon.ico|sitemap.xml|rewrite.cfm)($|/.*$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./rewrite.cfm/$1 [NS,L]
```

**Results from the last RewriteRule:**

[image: Results from the last RewriteRule]

**Results as they should be or when the last RewriteRule is commented out**

[image: Results as they should be or when the last RewriteRule is commented out]

I have tried numerous workarounds including adding the following but nothing has resolved the issue:

```
RewriteRule ^flex2gateway/$ [NS,T=application/x-amp,L]
```

Comment: I tried posting to http://www.helicontech.com/community/Helicon_Ape-8.html but their community login isn't working right now.

Comment: Seems like the response is blank also because content length is 0? What is that last rule for? Have you looked at the error logs? Also I would suggest you enable rewrite logs and provide the same with the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out and of course it was a simple fix!

Just add `jakarta|` to the `RewriteCond` pattern:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(jakarta|flex2gateway|jrunscripts|cfide|cfformgateway|cffileservlet|railo-context|lucee|files|images|javascripts|miscellaneous|stylesheets|robots.txt|favicon.ico|sitemap.xml|rewrite.cfm)($|/.*$) [NC]
```

ColdFusion 10 is now using `/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll` to process the `flex2gateway` path.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the folder **flex2gateway** actually exists and when you try to get the "/flex2gateway/" path, it tries to return the directory listing.

Try to add a rule for this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*/(flex2gateway|jrunscripts|cfide|cfformgateway|cffileservlet|railo-context|lucee|files|images|javascripts|miscellaneous|stylesheets)(/?)$[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./rewrite.cfm/$1 [NS,L]
```

which will redirect to "./rewrite.cfm/$1" script. Change this to your preferred target.

Comment: "/flex2gateway/" URL is not a file, nor a directory. It's a value intercepted by a servlet filter defined within ColdFusion in this case CF10. Also, the response body is empty when the last rewrite is uncommented.

Comment: @Micah I thought I got it :(, try adding "index.cfm" to your exclude rules, |rewrite.cfm|index.cfm). I think it gets redirected to it when nothing it matched. Try also swapping the rules, though I doubt this will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry you weren't quite able to come up with the solution but thanks for your great attempts! They encouraged me to keep trying. =)