# mod_rewrite ignores query strings and replaces ? with &

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I could not find a solution to this problem. Maybe because I don't know what to search for, but I am having difficulty setting up mod_rewrite.

I have URL `example.com/soutez` redirecting to `example.com/soutez.php` which is all fine and working using following settings:

```
RewriteRule ^soutez/?$ /soutez.php [L]
```

But the problem starts when I have a URL like `example.com/sutaz?fbclid=1324` and someone sends a POST form, which adds custom parameter `status=ok` (like `example.com/soutez?status=ok`).

Then for example URL like `example.com/soutez?fbclid=IwAR0GO5lq0VnVZS` on form send transforms URL to `example.com/soutez&fbclid=IwAR0GO5lq0VnVZS?status=ok` which is weird and incorrect and shows 404 because it adds new parameters to the end and changes first `?` with `&`.

Does anybody know how to setup `.htaccess` in order to make it work and let it show correctly `example.com/soutez?fbclid=IwAR0GO5lq0VnVZS&status=ok`?

Current `.htaccess` is as follows:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
# Specify search friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^soutez/?$ /soutez.php [L]
```

Comment: That seems unlikely. Only a look into the [rewrite log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite) can answer this though.

Comment: Most problems with rewrites and query strings stem from not using the `QSA` flag

Comment: There's something else going on here - the problem is not with the `.htaccess` code you posted. It's not clear from your question how these "custom parameters" are being sent/received and managed? "URL like `example.com/soutez?fbclid=IwAR0GO5lq0VnVZS` on form send transforms URL to `example.com/soutez&fbclid=IwAR0GO5lq0VnVZS?status=ok`" - Where is `status=ok` coming from?

Comment: Also, using mod_rewrite to simply remove the need for a file-extension is overkill (in my opinion). That's what `MultiViews` is for