# Why RewriteRule doesn't work as I expected, according the regular expression?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good morning,
I have a Virtual Host configured on an Apache2 server. The mod_rewrite module is active and functional.

I tested regular expressions on the site *https://regex101.com/* and it behaves like I expect.

I tested the *.htaccess* file on the *https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/* site and it works correctly.

I don't understand why, when I try it on the apache server it doesn't work.

Here is the complete *.htaccess* file

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(assets|locale)/(.*)$  user/$2/$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(/{0,1})user/([^/]+)(/?.*) user/$2.html [QSA,L]
```

**Virtual host Configuration**

```
Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

**Website structure**

```
mywebsite.local
    user/
        - .htaccess
        - index.html
        - app.html
```

**Tested URL**

```
http://mywebsite.local/user/index/
http://mywebsite.local/user/app/
http://mywebsite.local/user/app/dashboard/
http://mywebsite.local/user/app/planningWeek/current/
http://mywebsite.local/user/app/task/taskId/day/month/year/
```

**What I'm expected**

```
http://mywebsite.local/user/index/
go to index.html (it works)

http://mywebsite.local/user/app/
go to app.html (it works)

http://mywebsite.local/user/app/dashboard/
it must go to app.html but I have this error
"The requested URL /user/app.html/dashboard was not found on this server."
```

I don't understand why the regular expression is valid and the .htaccess file from the sites indicated works, but if I load it on the server no.

Thanks

Comment: the very first thing you need to do is change `+MultiViews` to `-MultiViews` (because it messes with your requests in more ways than you can imagine)

Comment: Next, you probably want to move `.htaccess` to the root folder of your website

Comment: (in fact, since you have access to apache .conf files, [you should not use .htaccess at all](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when))

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `mod_rewrite` is just substituting `app` for `app.html` in your example, thus generating `/user/app.html/dashboard` out of `/user/app/dashboard`.

If your `.htaccess` file works in the website you've tested it, could it be that there are any other components interfering in the request?

Maybe the rewrite logs can lead you to an answer? For further information see [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632952/2814332).

Hope it helps, kind regards.