# Apache url rewriting and loop

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

setting url rewriting to have nice urls, i have existing urls like that :
/xxx/test.php

but in the background, it is allways going to the same script with a query :
/xxx/index.php?id=test

with the following rewrite :

```
RewriteRule ^xxx/([0-9a-z\-]*)\.php$ /xxx/index\.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

it's working fine.

now, there are old urls still like /xxx/index.php?id=$1
and i want to get rid of these old urls, meaning I want all of them to be for the users like /xxx/test.php with a 301 redirect

i did a rewrite for this but then i'm entering a loop despite the L flag

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^xxx/index\.php$ /xxx/%1.php? [R=301,L]
```

? is it possible to handle that and how ?

and other to describe it is allways use the script :
/xxx/index.php?id=$1
but allways have the right url in the browser displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your existing

```
RewriteRule ^xxx/([0-9a-z\-]*)\.php$ /xxx/index\.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

which appears to work fine.

Add in these two lines before that which will catch if there is an id= and strip it out of the URL.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^xxx/([0-9a-z\-]*)\.php$ /xxx/index\.php?id=%1%2 [L,R=301]
```

- ^ start of query string
- ([^&])* any character except &
- (.*) any following characters

So if query string is `id=test&something=else` RewriteRule will append exactly that and nothing else as there is no more QSA flag.

Try those 3 lines together ([htaccess test website](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)), here is the full htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^xxx/([0-9a-z\-]*)\.php$ /xxx/index\.php?id=%1%2 [L]

RewriteRule ^xxx/([0-9a-z\-]*)\.php$ /xxx/index\.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: i have a 500 internal server error, i did add R=301, but still... let me check more

Comment: Ok, sorry my 301 was incorrect. Also, turning on mod rewrite logging might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632952/5514077

Comment: thanks for all your help; still looking for it but i accept your answer not to block you

Answer (score 0):

Make your RewriteRule not match index.php or remove the QSA flag.

Say you type test.php well now you will go to `index.php?id=test`

Then Rewrite occurs again and you will go to `index.php?id=index&id=test`

Then it will occur again because the page is different: `index.php?id=index&id=index&id=test etc.`

So add in your regex a negative lookahead: `xxx/(?!index)([0-9a-z\-]*)\.php`

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^xxx/(?!index)([0-9a-z\-]*)\.php$ /xxx/index\.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks. for the other regex i did that

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^xxx/index\.php$ /xxx/%1.php? [R=301,L]

but it is still doing a loop. where is my error ?

Comment: sorry, not working, still doing the loop, but i did add my other regex to make it clearer

Comment: your regex should be working but it is not, trying still to understand why it is not. I tried that too : ((?!index)[0-9a-z\-])*\.php and ((?!index)[0-9a-z\-]*)\.php

Comment: thanks for your help. the 2 regex are workinf separately but not set together

Comment: I'm re-reading your question and I believe you must do a condition "IF ?id= is present strip it, IF NOT do it the old way" so you can catch this problem that occurs only when using the old links like index.php?id=pagename