# Laravel Redirect for Weird Encoded Space

Tags: laravel, apache, redirect, urlencode

It seems we have some weird broken incoming links for our website that we would like to redirect. We are using Laravel on Apache.

Here is the incoming url: `/flannel-sheets%C2%A0`

Here is where we want to send it: `/flannel-sheets`

%C2%A0 seems to decode to a strange space.

I have tried these lines in the `web.php` file

```
$this->get( 'flannel-sheets%C2%A0', function() { return redirect( '/flannel-sheets' ); });
$this->get('flannel-sheets ', function() { return redirect( '/flannel-sheets' ); });
$this->get('flannel-sheets$nbsp;', function() { return redirect( '/flannel-sheets' ); });
```

I have also tried using Apache redirects in my `000-default.config` and `.htaccess` files

```
Redirect 301 /flannel-sheets%C2%A0 https://example.com/flannel-sheets
```

Neither of these methods are working for me. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is a non-breaking space *(0xC2 0xA0)*. `&nbsp;` Annoying to deal with these once they are in the wild, bad inbound links that is.

Using `mod_rewrite` is probably the best option here. Something like this would work...

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\xc2\xa0$ $1 [L,NE]
```

You'll want to check for those characters, not their URL encodings. I'm wondering if `mod_speling` offers anything useful for this scenario... not seeing anything so far.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. Your rewrite rule didn't work for me ):

Comment: Maybe explain what you mean by "didn't work".  Failed to match? https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=17959635-52a3-521e-bc79-b3d0017fcfcc

Comment: Odd, I have it in my htaccess file and it doesn't seem to match since it's not getting rewritten

Comment: Order of execution? If you need to get into debugging that stuff... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite Hard to write the pattern from here. Would help to know what the actual URI is. Like hex values, not what you see in a web browser or copy and paste. I think my pattern works if URI has a trailing non-breaking space.

Comment: I actually just used this (thanks to your code) 
RewriteRule ^flannel-sheets\xc2\xa0$ /flannel-sheets? [L,R=301]
And it worked!

Comment: Cool! I'm honestly not great with rewrites/regex so my confidence was waning ;) Crux is that `\xc2\xa0` part, sure you can adapt/build on it with some other examples.

Answer (score 1):

you can fix it using :

```
# remove spaces from start or after /
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)[\s%20]+(.+)$ $1$2 [L]

# remove spaces from end or before /
RewriteRule ^(.+?)[\s%20]+(/.*|)$ $1$2 [L]

# replace spaces by - in between
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L,R]
```

or you can receive the broken routes dynamically

```
$this->get( '/{route}', function($route) { 
//filter $route the way you need
 ); });
```

Comment: I don't think this pattern matches `[\s%20]`. Would working with a normal space though not NBSP.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. Your rewrite rules didn't work for me ): I could catch all routes that's true, just wish there was an easier way.