# Redirect to https with htaccess but not in develop with XAMPP

Tags: php, .htaccess, https, xampp

I am redirecting my URL to https with htaccess using this directives:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoled.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works Ok.

I need to do the same except with 127.0.0.1 while I develop PHP on XAMPP, so I added this condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^127.0.0.1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoled.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it continues sending the URL to https://www.yoled.com instead of using 127.0.0.1/index.php.

How can I set a RewriteCond for 127.0.0.1?

Thank you.

Comment: Not seeing the issue. Suggest trying to get some insight. See: [How to debug Apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Make sure you are not looking at a cached result from earier attempts. Always test using an anonymous browser window.

Comment: Asking for cached results? Really?

- Tested on Firefox and Chrome.
- Erased all navigation data with Ctrl+Shift+Delete in both browsers.
- Used !^127.0.0.1 and !127.0.0.1.
- Erased all .htaccess content setting just this segment.
- I've try at beginning of .htaccess.
- I've try at end of .htaccess.

The RewriteCond is not working for 127.0.0.1, and in LOCAL XAMPP redirect to Web page on Internet.