# Apache2 Rewrite Rules apply in different folder

Tags: apache, web, mod-rewrite, apache2, devops

Is it possible to have my ".htaccess" file with rewrite rules only apply in a folder it is in? As it is applying it to everything even other directories.

HTAccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ pages.php?page=$1

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you pls add your .htaccess file. Make sure not to include sensitive information.

Comment: Hey, I just did that.

Comment: The directives you've posted essentially already do as you require? The regex `^([^/]+)/?$` only matches a single path segment (ie. the current directory) and the preceding _condition_ already excludes directories (for any URL-paths that do end in a slash). (?)

Comment: Please give examples of URLs that, as you suggest, are being rewritten by the above directives but should not be.

Comment: So Issue is, whenever I use this RegEx all my CSS, Images, JS break. They result in a 404 and are also rewritten to the url like pages?php=page=somejshere

Comment: Are you sure the `REQUEST_FILENAME` contains a proper value at that stage of the apache request processing? Might try `REQUEST_URI` instead. See https://serverfault.com/a/1062617/393657. Also you can pimp the logging so it shows you more details about the rewrite: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632952/1614903. The latter might not be possible, in a shared hosting with no access to the apache config.