# RewriteRule: redirect html pages to "index.php?id="

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working in a home made poor CMS with PHP and HTML5 only. Internal links are passed as arguments to `index.php` with `?id=` and recovered with `$_GET['id']`.

My articles gonna be stored in `/articles` folder, images in `/img` and CSS and standard frame in `/`:

```
/articles
/img
404.php
footer.html
header.html
index.php
sidebar.html
style.css
```

Then i use:

```php
if ($_GET) {
    $page_file = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    $page_file = 'articles/about.html';
}

$body = file_get_contents($page_file);
```

Most links in sidebar (`sidebar.html`) and navigation menu (in `header.html`) will be to posts in articles folder. So, without `.htaccess` rewrite rules, this works:

```html
<a href="index.php?id=articles/LICENSE.html">
```

But i want to hide `index.php?id=`, so i can write this and it keep working:

```html
<a href="articles/LICENSE.html">
```

In both cases: `<base target="_top">`.

My `.htaccess` is not working well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$                     index.php        [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-d
RewriteRule (.*)                   index.php?id=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$           -                [L]
```

Everything works fine except that `<a href="articles/LICENSE.html">` is not redirecting to `index.php?id=articles/LICENSE.html` but to `articles/LICENSE.html`.

I tried many rules, some examples:

```
RewriteRule ^(articles/.*)             index.php?id=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^(articles/.*)             index.php?id=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(articles\/.*)            index.php?id=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?id=articles/$1  [QSA,L]
...
```

And others. No way.

One strange thing is that, if i change `index.php` to:

```php
$body = file_get_contents('articles/'.$page_file);
or
$body = file_get_contents("articles/$page_file");
```

And links to:

```html
<a href="LICENSE.html">
```

And keep rules with just:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$                     index.php        [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-d
RewriteRule (.*)                   index.php?id=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$           -                [L]
```

It works!

Comment: _"is not redirecting to index.php?id=articles/LICENSE.html but to articles/LICENSE.html"_ - so that is _not_ a redirect then, you simply landed exactly where the link pointed to. Your `articles/LICENSE.html` does actually exist as a file here, correct? So the RewriteConds, which explicitly check if what was requested does _not_ match onto an extsting file or folder, prevent the following RewriteRule from applying.

Comment: Correct, `articles/LICENSE.html` does exist. How should i write this, please?

Comment: If you want this for all files with the suffix `.html`, then don't put any RewriteConds before the rule, and make the rule itself `RewriteRule (.*\.html)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Not working...
```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$                                 index.php                   [L]
RewriteRule (.*\.html)$                        index.php?id=$1             [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}                !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}                !-d
RewriteRule (.*)                               index.php?id=$1             [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$                       -                           [L]
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful problem description. What happens? No rewrite? Errors?

Comment: It keep going to articles/LICENSE.html, nothing changes.

Comment: Should work fine, https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=6774b5e8-2e16-4f5b-bf46-604656461723 agrees.

Comment: When in doubt, you can always enable some rewrite logging (assuming you have the necessary access to the server configuration), and then check what is going on in detail.

Comment: Loved that site! If you remove the line `RewriteRule (.*\.html)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]` in that site, it works too.

Comment: That tool can not verify if the requested URL matched an existing file or not, so bot the RewriteConds are true, and therefor the request would get rewritten by the following rule. But that doesn't match your actual scenario.

Comment: I do have access, it's LAMP. How to enable rewrite logging?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9632852/1427878

Comment: I was unable to activate log, but after a cache clean and tried also in Firefox, it works partially. Link redirects to `index.php?id=` but: CSS is no longer loaded, and if i click LICENSE link many times it will become: `articles/articles/articles/articles/articles/articles/LICENSE.html`

Comment: That's because how relative URLs work. From the browser's perspective, you are "in" the `/articles/` folder, so the relative URL `articles/LICENSE.html` resolved against that, results in `/articles/articles/LICENSE.html`. Use root-relative URLs, starting with a leading slash.

Comment: Ah perfect! My site is in `/var/www/html/magazine` with `<a href="/magazine/articles/LICENSE.html">`it works without repetition, it was `<a href="articles/LICENSE.html">. Now will test CSS.

Comment: Done! It's working now! Thank you very much. CSS and Images just needed root-relative URLs too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## RESOLVED

[@cbroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) helped me.

The `articles/LICENSE.html` actually exist as a file.

Right `.htaccess` to deal with that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*\.html)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Also, to avoid clicking LICENSE link many times and become: `/articles/articles/.../articles/articles/LICENSE.html`, i must use root relative URLs.

That's because how relative URLs work. From the browser's perspective, you are "in" the /articles/ folder, so the relative URL articles/LICENSE.html resolved against that, results in /articles/articles/LICENSE.html. Use root-relative URLs, starting with a leading slash.

**Right:**

```html
<a href="/articles/LICENSE.html">
```

**Wrong:**

```html
<a href="articles/LICENSE.html">
```