.htaccess for replacing Query parameters with forward slash
I'm trying to create an .htaccess file to replace query parameters with a forward slash.
The URL changes successfully but I get a 404.
Basically, I want the url to be like:
domain.com/value
Instead of:
domain.com/index.php?id=value
This is my .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^value$ index.php?id=value [L]


Solution
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(\S+?)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]


Surprised you are getting a 404, and not an "endless" redirect. First you request /value, so the first condition isn't true, and the second rule will internally rewrite this to index.php?id=value. Then the whole process starts again. Now the first condition is true, so your first rule will externally redirect this to /value again ... Try and replace the L flag in the second rule with the END flag instead. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end

Also a good idea to enable rewrite logging - so you can see what is actually happening from apache's perspective https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632952/761202

@CBroe I'm getting the same result

Remove the RewriteCond and the first RewriteRule, and then request /index.php?id=value and /value in a private browser window (to exclude cached 301 redirects falsifying the results.) If the former gives you the expected result, but the latter doesn't - then that would indicate, that no rewriting happened at all. Could be that your server is not even configured to use .htaccess files to begin with - write some gibberish like jsdfhsfe at the start of the file to check, that should give you a 500 Internal Server Error then, if your server does evaluate .htaccess files.
