# Custom WordPress Rewrite returns 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add several custom WordPress rewrites to a directory that contains some special pages. I have added a directory  named `custom`, which contains all of the custom pages.

I have added rewrite rules, but for some reason whenever I try to access them, I get a 404 error. Here is a copy of my `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# BEGIN Custom
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~meddept/
RewriteRule ^contact-us/? /~meddept/custom/contact.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END Custom

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~meddept/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~meddept/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The problem comes when trying to access `contact-us/`. Visiting `/custom/contact.php` also returns the same 404 error, even though the file definitely exists...

```
RewriteRule: http://82.147.22.3/~meddept/contact-us/
Direct file: http://82.147.22.3/~meddept/custom/contact.php
```

Can anyone explain why the first rule (with `L` flag) is failing? I've tried with the numerous [WordPress functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) as well, but receive the same result...

Comment: As both a stackfellow and namefellow (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54502/is-there-a-word-for-someone-with-the-same-name), I agree with @benm, this is BS.

Comment: Have you sure checked ownership of entries here: custom/*.*?

Comment: @jacouh Yes. Both user and group ownerships match WP root files...

Comment: I was going to suggest the same as @jacouh. Is custom RX and contact.php R.

Comment: What happens in `contact.php` ? are you loading WP codebase and displaying custom html in it?

Comment: @Ben exactly. `contact.php` simply has: 

`require('../wp-blog-header.php');
get_header();
get_footer();`

Comment: @BenM You need to `exit()` before wordpress takes over completely, otherwise 404..

Comment: after `get_footer()` for instance..

Comment: Sure, theses rules are in ~meddept/.htaccess, but not in ~meddept/custom/.htaccess ...

Comment: @BenM There are better ways to do this though, for instance `page-$id.php` or `page-$slug.php` files in your template folder (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Comment: @Ben adding `exit()` after `get_footer()` has no effect. @jacouh yes, the rules are `~meddept/.htaccess`.

Comment: @BenM. See my last comment and link, there's way better options to do what you're trying to do in Wordpress..

Comment: @Ben I know there are other ways to achieve this, but the point remains that the rewrites *should* work...

Comment: I've visited http://82.147.22.3/~meddept/custom/contact.php, 404 error also.

Comment: @jacouh Correct, please read my question. If you visit http://82.147.22.3/~meddept/custom/ you can clearly see the file exists...

Comment: @BenM You *can* eat soup with a fork, it's just way easier with a spoon..

Comment: You are all OK, simply you send a soft 404 header using PHP ?

Comment: @jacouh No, there is no 404 header being sent from the file.

Comment: @Ben - nice analogy. That having been said, I really think it's easier just for me to handle this with `.htaccess`. I need some complex functionality within `contact.php` (as an example), which isn't suited to insertion directly into a WP Template file, or indeed the template's `functions.php` file. There's no reason why the rewrite shouldn't work as far as I can tell...

Comment: @BenM You're making a custom php file that runs `require('../wp-blog-header.php'); get_header(); get_footer();` (quoting you ;)  How is that different?

Comment: Haha, that's a proof-of-concept for now. There will be a **lot** more functionality when the route is working...

Comment: Sounds complicated, wish enlightenment comes to you soon ;)

Comment: Please try custom/contact.php: <?php
echo "I'm contact.php";
?>

Comment: Adding a plain `echo` statement to `contact.php` no longer produces the 404. Is it possible to have WordPress ignore the permalink lookup?

Comment: It's because WordPress header , you should correct it easily...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `404` header was being caused by WordPress. Since I was using WordPress to handle the outputting of the header and footer, and there was no WordPress page defined, WP returned (incorrectly) a 404.

I was able to circumvent this by setting up The Loop **before** handling my code. Essentially, I updated `contact.php` to appear as follows:

```
<?php

require('../wp-blog-header.php');

// Fix WordPress false 404s:
$wp->init();
$wp->parse_request();
$wp->query_posts();
$wp->register_globals();
$wp->send_headers();

get_header();

echo 'this is my content';

get_footer();
?>
```

And now everything works (including the custom routes) as expected.

Comment: +1 to your question & answer for posting a solution. I removed `.htaccess, mod_rewrite` tags since that is unrelated.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution.. I still think it's a silly way to do it though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think your problem is, that you rewrite the base and then access the rest. This might work:

```
# BEGIN Custom
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~meddept/
RewriteRule ^contact-us/? custom/contact.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END Custom
```

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried this, and it produces the same results.

Comment: What if you remove the custom rewrite and just add `RewriteRule ^contact-us/ /~meddept/custom/contact.php [L]` to the existing one ( right below index.php redirect ) ?

Comment: The same result. 404s on both counts.

Comment: Yes. The custom rewrites from WordPress work fine: http://82.147.22.3/~meddept/about-us/

Comment: Did you try debugging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738170/how-to-debug-htaccess-rewrite-script it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40955/discussion-between-dainis-abols-and-benm)