# Error on rewriting URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite URL with help of ".htaccess" file, but having some problem.

http://domian.in/code.php?code=hby5

to

http://domian.in/hby5

I used this below htaccess code but having "**500 Internal Server Error**".

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /code.php?code=$1 [L]
```

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Switch on the debug mode of apache. So you can see if your  rewirting works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738170/how-to-debug-htaccess-rewrite-script

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is causing an infinite internal redirection ( `/code.php => /code.php....` ) because `([^/]*)` also matches your rewrite destination `/code.php` and rewrites it to itself , to fix this ,you need to exclude the target `/code.php` from the rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((?!code\.php)[^/]*)$ /code.php?code=$1 [L]
```