# Is there a log that records 301 redirects in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, logging

I have a few 301 redirects in my .htaccess file.  Was curious if they get logged in any specific logs?

Thank you

Comment: No it is not logged unless you enable `RewriteLog`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14793481/4636715) may help you: `LogLevel warn rewrite:trace8` . Your version also counts for the pinpoint method you should use.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

You're going to want to add the following to your `VirtualHost` config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log
  RewriteLogLevel 3
</IfModule>
```

Comment: +1 for the link to the documentation! Unfortunately it references an outdated version. You might want to refer to the current version, especially since things changed for version 2.4 of the apache http server when it comes to rewrite logging...

Comment: Not going to lie, so many different answers and links.  Including having to change multiple files.  Am afraid I'll ruin an already working server.

Comment: @SergioD.Caplan - Spin up a dev server on DigitalOcean, Azure, AWS or Vultr and just create a apache2 web server and test it before deploying to production.

Comment: To anyone reading this, it seems I can't do this on a GoDaddy shared server because I don't have full access.  I have a server at home that I use for development.  If I make it host my GoDaddy account (not email), will I still be able to access all these files?  Am assuming yes, but the server side is new to me.